# Parameters of neis nigleh and neis nistar?

Tags: halacha, purim, miracle, hallel, yom-haatzmaut

What are the Halachic parameters and definition of a neis nistar versus a neis nigleh?

For example: I heard recently from a Rav that one reason brought not to say hallel on Yom Ha’atzma’ut is that even though (the reason-giver believes) there was a neis on Yom Ha’atzma’ut, we don’t say hallel because the neis was “hidden”.

So what exactly is a neis nistar?

Comment: I’m having a hard time finding good tags for this question as there is no “neis” or “Nissim” rag, and as I’m on a cellphone I can’t create one. So if someone could edit those in I’d be grateful.

Comment: Better sourcing that this category is actually Halakhically relevant would improve this question

Comment: Sounds like a bit strange reasoning. It seems that neither Rosh Hodesh, Shavuot or Succot involved revealed miracles. Yet, we say Hallel on those occasions.

Comment: Re tagging - it seems hat the focus of your question is more on the parameters on when we say Hallel, not the definitions of the two types of miracles.

Comment: @DanF 1) the reason hallel is said on Yom ha’atzma’ut (by some people) is because a neis happened. Some reject this and say that no neis happened, and some (like I said in my question) say that a neis happened, but it was a “hidden” neis. I want to know what “hidden” means exactly, and, in comparison, what “revealed means by nissim. 2) no my question is what the types of nissim are. The hallel case is just a backdrop and an example where this would matter (according to those dei’os).

Comment: @Loani Did the rav give a source? Can you ask him? It's probably the most direct way to find out what he meant.

Comment: @WAF I asked him, but he said that, unfortunately, he doesn’t remember where he saw this reason.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to first ask for the source for his reason, and then if we establish that it is 'real' (as in, its context wasn't just aggadic) then you can ask for parameters

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105358/what-is-the-source-for-this-reason

Comment: My impression was that Hannukah and Purim were both Nisim Nistarim, because there were no open supernatural miracles like in Yetziat Mitzrayim. In this sense, they are similar to Yom Ha'atzmaut (for those who believe miracles occurred then).

Comment: @Daniel really? I always thought that the miracle of the oil jar was a neis nigleh.

Comment: If the main miracle is about the oil jar, why isn't that miracle mentioned in Al Hanisim? No one would make a holiday just because light lasted longer than normal.

Comment: @Daniel Kagan see here left column: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&st=&pgnum=181&hilite=