# What is the source for not saying Hallel because it is a "hidden miracle"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, miracle, hallel, yom-haatzmaut

I heard recently from a Rav that one reason brought not to say hallel on Yom Ha’atzma’ut is that even though (the reason-giver believes) there was a miracle on Yom Ha’atzma’ut, we don’t say hallel because the miracle was “hidden”. Unfortunately the Rav didn’t give a source for this reason. Does anyone know what the source is for this reason?

Comment: Strange reason, saying _halel_ because of a miracle. I mean, [the spies' tongues' growing](/q/83376/170) was a miracle, but we don't say _halel_ that day.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105326/parameters-of-neis-nigleh-and-neis-nistar

Comment: @msh210 he probably meant that it was a good miracle. Or a miracle that drastically changed the Jews’ lives (like Yetzias Mitzraim)

Comment: @msh210 Arachin 10b gives the miracle as the reason for saying Hallel on Chanukah, and wonders why the miracle of Purim is not a reason to say Hallel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Abudarham](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Abudirham) ([here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&st=&pgnum=181&hilite=), left column) quotes such reasoning in the name of [R. Asher](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asher_ben_Meshullam) of Lunel, but the nuance of his reasoning is not so much that the miracle is “hidden”, rather it’s when the miracle is ostensibly natural/ordinary one does not consider it a miracle (vis-a-vis the blessing “... a miracle was done for me...” and, by extension, Hallel). (Cf. R. Ovadiah Yosef, Yabia Omer VI O.C. 41)

Comment: How does that relate to Al Hanisim on Purim?